# Stochastic integral, simple process and Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

What I want to show is that $$\int_0^t\phi^n_t \, dB_s = \sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}B_{t_{i-1}^n}(B_{t_{i}^n}-B_{t_{i-1}^n}) \to \int_0^tB_s\,dB_s$$
where $\phi^n_t=\sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}B_{t_{i-1}^n} \mathbb1_{(t_{i-1}^n, t_i^n)}(t)$.

For doing so is sufficient to prove that $$E\bigg[\int_0^t(\phi^n_t-B_s)^2\,ds\bigg] = \|\phi^n_t-B_s\|_{\lambda^2}\to0$$

Then $$\int_0^t\phi^n_t\,dB_s\to\int_0^tB_s\,dB_s$$ in $L^2$ follows by the construction of the stochastic integral.

However this is the construction followed starting from a simple process, but in this case $\phi^n_t=\sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}B_{t_{i-1}^n} \mathbb1_{(t_{i-1}^n, t_i^n)}(t)$ is it a simple process? For being a simple process $B_{t_{i-1}^n}$ should be a bounded random variable. Is it the case? It seems to me that depend also on time (and so is not a random variable but a stochastic process) and it also seems to me that is not bounded since a B.M reaches every point an infinite number of times. And finally, if it is not a simple process why this construction still hold?

Comment: Isn't the thing that you really want to use just the Ito isometry here? That tells you that $\bigg\| \int_0^t \phi_s^n - B_s dB_s \bigg \|_{L^2(\mathbb{P})}^2 = E\bigg[\int_0^t(\phi^n_s-B_s)^2\,ds\bigg]$

Comment: yes that's true, this would explain the procedure. I thought that there was something deeper connected to simple processes. So this is not the case and $\phi^n$ is not a simple process, right?

Comment: Every construction I've seen of the Ito integral via simple processes has required that the random variables taking the place of $B_{t_i^n}$ be bounded so yes, you're right.

Comment: @Alias__: I think $\phi^n_t=\sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}B_{t_{i-1}^n} \mathbb1_{(t_{i-1}^n, t_i^n)}(t)$ is a simple process. It is a way to make a simple process out of a B.M. by taking the value of the B.M at specific time $t^n_{i-1}$ and keeping it constant for the interval $t^n_{i}-t^n_{i-1}.$ Also $B_{t_{i-1}^n}$ is a normal random variable and is integrable.

Comment: @RhysSteele what do you think about the answer of UBM? this is a matter that always put me in difficulty. Is it right that $B_{t_{i-1}}$is a random variable (what I mean is that It does not depend on time, but only on $\omega$? I think yes.. anyway I think that $\phi^n $ is not a simple process because $B_{t_{i-1}}$ is not bounded (is a random variable but not bounded, since a B.M reaches every point an infinite number of times)

Comment: @Alias__: In Capinski's book they just require the process to be square-integrable, that's why my comment. So if in your notes or book the definition says bounded meaning for every $\omega,$ then forget about my comment.

Comment: This discussion is just an example of why I put the qualifier "Every construction I've seen..." in my last comment. I'm not familiar with Capinski's book but its plausible it constructs the integral in a way that doesnt require simple processes to be bounded. Either way, you should work with the definition of a simple process you started with.